# how to create setup file and install on clients pc

Tags: c#, sql-server, installation, ef-code-first, setup-project

hi I made a simple program with using code first .
this program only insert and shows name and family
i dont know how to create setup  file
and i want to know that what applications should be installed on clients pc to run my program after installing it .

```
public class human
{
  public int id {get;set;}
  public string  name {get;set;}
  public string  family {get;set;}

}
public class db:dbcontext
{
  public db ():base ("x"){}
  public dbset<human > humans {get;set;}

}
```

```
human h =new human ();
db db1 =new db();
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  h.name =textbox1.text;
  h.family=textbox2.text;
  db1.humans.Add(h);
  db1.SaveChanges();
  Datagridview1.datasource=db1.humans.tolist();
}
```

Comment: You're probably better to find tutorials about how to create .NET installers. But it looks like your program also requires SQL Server?

Comment: I personnaly use [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) (with [ISTool (inactive)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/istool/) or there is [Inno Script Studio](https://www.kymoto.org/products/inno-script-studio/)), that is more simple and powerfull but different from the [Visual Studio Setup Installer Template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects). Also take a look at [4 Great Tools to Create Windows Installer Packages](https://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/4-tools-to-create-windows-installer-packages/)

Comment: yes it needs sql server but i dont know witch kind of sql should i install help  me if you know

Comment: you mean which edition of SQL Server? To be honest, if you're making such a simple program, something as complex as SQL Server is unnecessary overhead, and makes the installation a lot harder. For a local database on a simple application it would be a lot better to use a simple file-based database such as SQLite. Then all you have to do is include the database file in with the rest of the application files (or even make the application create one on first use.)

Comment: u mean i should only intsall setup file on a camputer that sqllite is installed on that??

Comment: there is no need to install ssms on clients pc ??

Comment: There would be no need to install SSMS in either case - that's only a front-end for SQL server management...your users don't need that. So if you use SQL server, you have to install SQL server _backend_. If you use SQLite, you just copy a simple database file into the PC along with the application files. Go and read about SQlite and find tutorials showing you how to use it with .Net, and you can see it's quite simple.